# Jmeter: collaborative script editing

Tags: jmeter, sharing

Does anyone know if is possible to do collaborative editing on the same JMeter script?
One script, several people working on the same script.

Comment: Have you tried opening the same file in more than one JMeter instance, save it in one, and then see if the file is updated in the other instance?

Answer (score 3):

1. I would suggest using something like github for version control if you want multiple people working on the script at the same time. This is VERY common for workflows and ensures you know who did what. As an added bonus you can kinda see visually what the changes and diffs are since the .jmx script is an XML file.
2. There are a few features that help with distributed script creation such as:

Include Controller
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller

Templates
http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/templates-or-how-to-speed-up-your-tests-scripting-with-jmeter/

Test Fragments
http://hoborglabs.com/en/blog/jmeter-jmx-fragmentation

Answer (score 0):

No, JMeter doesn't support this feature